# Should WPFToolkit Accordion "Stretch" VerticalAlignment be respected by AccordionItems?

Tags: .net, wpf, accordion, wpftoolkit

I want to reproduce the behavior similar to the Outlook bar and found the WPFToolkit's Accordion control.  I've created a test app from the WPFToolkit (Feb. 2010) sample application (below) I'm having trouble understanding the behavior.

```
<Window x:Class="AccordionTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="DimGray">
<Grid Background="Red">
    <toolkit:Accordion x:Name="acc" SelectionMode="One" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <toolkit:AccordionItem Content="item 1" Header="Item 1"  />
        <toolkit:AccordionItem Content="item 2" Header="Item 2" />
        <toolkit:AccordionItem Content="item 3" Header="Item 3" />
    </toolkit:Accordion>
</Grid>
```

I have the `VerticalAlignment` set to `Stretch` and the Accordion itself stretches from top to bottom of the form - but the accordion items do not.  Initially the first item ("Item 1") is stretched but if I then select the other items, they don't expand and stretch to fill the space.

So the Outlook behavior seems to work at load time but when I select the items, the control does not behave as expected.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I copied your exact code into a new wpf project. When I click any of the items, it does expand to fill the vertical space (all blue). Do you have some code-behind or anything?

Comment: @Paul Hoenecke:  I simply created a new WPF Application and copied the code above from the WPF Sample Project.  The only thing that maybe different is that I build the WPFToolkit and the Controls.Layout.Toolkit dlls in the same solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a bit more regarding VerticalAlignment, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801708/wpf-accordion-verticalalignment-bug) that has a solution:

> You can also set the Accordion SelectionSequence property to CollapseBeforeExpand.
>
> This bug is due to timing problems of the expanding/collapsing animation of each accordion item (when both expanding and collapsing happens simultaneously) with the layout update of the Accordion which messes up the size available for expansion.

This seems to solve my problem.